# XSLT query coming up as false

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, xslt, content-query-web-part

Any ideas why query results is coming up as false, although values are the same?

```
    <xsl:value-of select="../../../Cascade/Rows/Row/@Title@DocumentCategory=../../../DocumentCategory/Rows/Row/@Title" disable-output-escaping="yes" ></xsl:value-of>
```

Please note, I am using a content query webpart, and the Cascade library contains a lookup column from the Document Category list.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your filter is malformed, the filter should be enclosed in square brackets like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../../Cascade/Rows/Row/@Title[@DocumentCategory=../../../DocumentCategory/Rows/Row/@Title]" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```